# Can each program or application run with a different locale?

Tags: debian, locale, application

From what I know, if I want to run an application with a different locale, I have to run a terminal, then enter

```
export LANG=xx_XX.UTF8
```

and then run the command. The problem came up when I wanted to get a command run from a launcher, where predetermining the locale was not possible.

Apart from that, I realized I want to run some programs with one locale and other ones with another. I know that many programs' locale can be changed from their preferences after the they're started (e.g. firefox) but there are other ones where that is impossible.

So, my question is, can I have something like a configuration file along with /etc/default/locale where there could be an (incomplete) list of programs with their preferred localization which will override the localization of the system?

My distro is Debian Wheezy, if that's relevant.

Comment: You _can_ use a custom exec field in your launchers e.g. `Exec=env LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 myapp`